# NetBeans 7.0.1 good C++ program execution "RUN FAILED"

Tags: c++, netbeans, netbeans-7

Working inside NetBeans 7.0.1, fresh install on Ubuntu 13.10.

I have a known good C++ program.

I finally get it to compile and link.

When I press the Netbeans Run Main Project triangle, the execution breaks with

> java.util.MissingResourceException: bin/nativeexecution/Linux-x86/pty
>
> RUN FAILED

What's going on, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 7):

This is a NetBeans output-window setting problem.

NetBeans comes up with C++ projects defaulting to "Internal Terminal".  This is not working on your present configuration.

The answer is to switch your output to "External Terminal", which pops up a separate purple terminal typing console in its own window for your interaction, or "Standard Output",which presents the output in the expected white subpane below.

Do this by:

```
Right-mouse-click on your project name -> Properties
on the left side, in the "Categories:" column, select * Run
on the right side, beside the >General -> Console Type:,   
  change the pulldown menu from "Internal Menu" into "Standard Output".
Hit the OK button at the bottom to lock it in.
```

Now your project will run, forever after, when you ask it to.

Answer (score 0):

according to [this netbeans forum post](https://forums.netbeans.org/topic48020.html) package of netbeans 7.0.1 is lacking some files.
Removing version from repo and installing from [netbeans download site](https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) worked like a charm for me and nb forum OP.
So problem is also in ubuntu 14.04.

Also repo version is little out-of-date and NB have nice .sh installer. Just remember to install some JDK from repo or anywhere else.